# Kill a Homology class $[\beta] \in H_k(X)$ only by attaching $(k+1)$-cells

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a $n$-dimensional dimensional CW-complex build of skeleta $(X_0,X_1,...,X_k ,..., X_n) $. Let $[\beta] \in H_k(X)$ a *non zero* homology class which by definition can be represented by a formal sum $\beta= \sum_i a_i \sigma_i^k$ which is *not* contained in the image of the boundary map $\partial_{k+1}: C_{k+1}(X) \to C_k(X)$ and where only finitely many $a_i$ are non zero and  $\sigma_i^k $ represent the $k$-cells of $X$, which freely generate by construction $C_k(X)$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

**Question:** How to show that $X$ can be modified to another CW complex $X'$ obtained from $X$ by *only* glueing some additional $k+1$-cells to it in the way that $\beta$ lies in the image of the boundary map $\partial_{k+1}: C_{k+1}(X') \to C_k(X')= C_k(X)$? Is this procedure always possible? In other words to modify $X$ in the way such that

1. the homology class $[\beta] $ get killed
2. the homology below $k$ and $2$-dimensions above $k$ not changes, ie the canonical inclusion $\iota: X \to X'$ induces identity map $\iota_k= \text{id}: H_m(X) \to H_m(X')$ for $k > m $ or $m \ge k+2$

Note that by construction of the associated [cell complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_homology) if $X$ is obtained from $X$ by gluing only some $k+1$-cells, the free groups $C_m(X')$ and differentials $\partial_m$ not change as long as $k > m $ or $m \ge k+2$. So the question reduces to the problem if it's always possible to attach $k+1$-cells $e_1^{k+1}, e_2^{k+1}, ..., e_d^{k+1}$ to $X$ in the way that $\beta$ lies in the differential

$$\partial'_{k+1}: C_{k+1}(X'):=C_{k+1}(X) \bigoplus \oplus_{i=1}^d \mathbb{Z} e_i^{k+1} \to C_k(X')=C_k(X) $$

induced by attaching maps. Note that not every map $\phi: C_{k+1}(X) \to C_k(X)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules comes from geometry, i.e. is induced by attaching map of cells. That makes it (at least for me) hard, to decide if such pure geometric modification on $X$ is always realizable.

Comment: You can turn any one of the $\sigma_i^k$ into a boundary by attaching a $k+1$ cell using $\sigma_i^k$ as attaching map. If you do that for each of the sigmas that appear in $\beta$ you turn this into a boundary, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I'm not sure if that always work. Recall that a $k$-cell $\sigma_i^k$ is given by a map $\sigma_i^k: D^k \to X_k$ such that $\sigma_i^k(\partial D^k) \subset X_{k-1}$. In general $\sigma_i^k(\partial D^k)$ is not a point. But in order to attach a $k+1$-cell - let call it $e^{k+1}  \cong D^{k+1}$ - using  $\sigma_i^k$ to $X$ as you suggest, the associated map $\sigma_i^k(\partial D^k) \subset X_{k+1}$ should factor through $D^k/\partial D^k \cong S^k \cong \partial e^{k+1}$, but this requires that $\sigma_i^k(\partial D^k)$ must be a point, or do I missing something?

Comment: Hatcher's Proposition 4C.1 may be relevant in the simply connected case.

Comment: @user7391733 The only constraint on the image of the attaching map is that it must lie in the $k-1$ skeleton. For example a CW-structure on $\mathbb S^2$ can be given by using a single 0-cell $X_0 = e^0$ (a point) and then attaching a $\mathbb D^2$ so that $\partial \mathbb D^2\to X_0$ is the constant map. This gives $\mathbb S^2 = e^0 \cup e^2$.

Comment: @Mariano: a typo in my comment: 3rd line: ...  the associated map $\sigma_i^k(\partial D^k) \subset X_{k-1}$ should factor through $ D^k/\partial D^k \cong S^k \cong \partial e^{k+1}$...

Comment: @JohnPalmieri: that's interesting. So in case $X$ simply connected it can be replaced by a CW space $Z$ where each "algebraic" generator of a summand in the girect sum decomposition $H_k(X)=H_k(Z) = \oplus_i \mathbb{Z}/(a_i) \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}^m$ comes from a "geometric" $k$-cell? The decomposition of  $H_k(X)$ we bocome 'for free' because of [this structure Thm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) for finitely gen modules over PID's (in our case $\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: @Overflowian: You mean that when we want to attach 
a $k$-cell to $X$ via contin map $\sigma^k: D^k \to X_k \subset X$ 
then the only condition/restriction which this map should
satisfy is that $\sigma^k(\partial D^k) \subset X_{k-1}$.
I agree, but the point with which I disagree or still not understand 
is what @ Mariano suggested, namely 
that if
$\sigma^k: D^k \to X_k$ is a $k$-cell of $X$ then it's 
homology class can be be killed by attaching a 
$(k+1)$-cell to $X$ along "attaching map" $f: \partial D^{k+1}
\to X_k$ using the previos map $\sigma^k$ as attaching map.

Comment: I doubt that it would be well defined in general, since if 
$f$ *would be* induced by $\sigma^k$, then this implies
that $\sigma^k(\partial D^k)$ must be homotopic to a point, otherwise
I not see how $\sigma^k: D^k \to X_k \subset X$ can induce
a well defined attaching map $f: \partial D^{k+1}
\to X_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\beta$ is the fundamental class of a torus $X = S^1 \times S^1$ then any map $S^2 \to X$ is nullhomotopic so attaching $3$-cells is the same as taking the wedge sum with $3$-spheres, which does not affect $H_2$.

On the other hand it *is* possible to kill $\beta$ by attaching $k$-cells if $X$ is $(k-1)$-connected, since then the map $\pi_k(X) \to H_k(X)$ is surjective.

Comment: alright I see, because $\pi_2(S^1 \times S^1) = \pi_2(S_1) \times  \pi_2(S_1)$ and  $\pi_2(S_1)=0 $ it's not possible to kill $\beta$ via attaching $k+1$-cells! Thanks for the example!

Comment: About one point I still not pretty sure. Is it in general always true that if $X$ is a CW-complex and $\pi_k(X)= 0$ (ie every attaching map $f: S^k \to X_k$ of a $(k+1)$-cell is homotopic to constant map), then any new CW-complex $X'$ obtained from $X$ only by attaching a $(k+1)$-cell is homotopic to wedge product $X \vee D^{k+1}$, if $X$ is $(k-1)$-connected? Why?

Comment: The reason why I still doubt about it is that it is known that pushforwards are not compatible with homotopy (eg $D^2 \coprod_{S^1} D^2 = S^2$ is not homotopic to a point even if $D^2$ are). In our case by definition $X_{k+1}= X_k \coprod_{f^k: S^k \to X_k}  D^{k+1}$ and therefore I not understand why $X_{k+1}'$ should be homotopic to $X_{k+1}$ if we exchange the attaching maps $f^k: S^k \to X_k$ by homotopic ones, which by assumption $\pi_k(X)=0$ can be choosen to be constant maps.

Comment: Does it help to think of attaching a $(k+1)$-cell as the *homotopy* pushout of $* \leftarrow S^k \to X_k$?

Comment: yes definitely :) I think that exactly such kind of troubles can be taken as motivation for introducing homotopy pushouts!

Comment: But how to check that attachment of $(k+1)$-cell is homotopy pushout of $* \leftarrow S^k \to X_k$ and not only the "usual" pushout $D^{k+1}  \leftarrow S^k \to X_k$?

Comment: It should agree with the standard construction of homotopy pushouts. If you're still having difficulty I think it deserves to be a separate question rather than continuing in the comments here.