# Effects on CW-complexes by replacing attatching maps by homotopic ones

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a $n$-dimensional dimensional CW-complex and $\pi_k(X)=0$ for $ n \ge k >1$. Therefore obviously by construction every attaching map $f_i^k: S^k \to X^{(k)}$ of a $(k+1)$-cell $e_i^{k+1}$ is homotopic to constant map.

What are the weakest conditions such that the $k+1$-skeleton $X^{(k+1)}$ which is inductively constructed as pushout

$$X^{(k+1)} := X^{(k)} \coprod_{f_i^k: S^k \to X^{(k)}} (\coprod_i D^{k+1})$$

is homotopic to

$$(X^{(k+1)})':=X^{(k)} \coprod_{c_i^k \in X^{(k)}} (\coprod_i D^{k+1}) =  X^{(k)} \bigvee_i S^k  $$

where $c_i^k \simeq f_i^k: S^k \to X^{(k)}$ are the constant maps homotopic to attaching maps $f_i^k$ with resepect the $(k+1)$-cells $e_i^{k+1} \cong D^{k+1}$.

More generally, what are the weakest conditions under which if $X,Y,Z$ are CW-complexes $X \subset Y$ is an inclusion (as sub CW complex, and therefore a *cofibration*) and $f: X \to Z$ homotopic to constant map $c $, then the pushout $Y \coprod_{f, X} Z$ is homotopic to $Y/X \coprod_c Z = Y/X \vee_c Z$.

The question is motivated by [this counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4637015) showing that it's not always possible to kill certain $k$-homology classes by attaching $(k+1)$-cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer the "More generally" question. No extra conditions are needed. If $j\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is a cofibration and $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Z$ are homotopic maps, then $Y\cup_fZ$ and $Y\cup_gZ$ are homotopy-equivalent rel $Z$. The spaces need not be CW-complexes for this. Note that if $g$ is constant with value $z$, the attaching space $Y\cup_gZ=Y/X\vee Z$ (wedged together at $X/X$ and $z$). An elementary discussion of this can be found in Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf), Proposition 0.18 (he states it only for CW pairs, but that is not necessary). For more abstract perspectives, this also follows from Theorem 5.1.9 or Proposition 5.3.4 in tom Dieck's Algebraic Topology.

However, I do not believe this "More generally" question is actually a generalization of what you ask before. The condition that $\pi_k(X)=0$ does *not* imply $\pi_k(X^{(k)})=0$, so it is not true that the attaching maps $S^k\rightarrow X^{(k)}$ are homotopic to constant maps. For example, take $X=D^2$, which is even contractible, but the attaching map $\mathrm{id}\colon S^1\rightarrow S^1$ of the $2$-cell is not homotopic to a constant as $S^1$ is not contractible.

Comment: so in the answer of the linked question the key point is *not* $\pi_k(X)=0$, which as you said not implies $\pi_k(X^{(k)})=0$ since a homotopy to constant map could pass through the $X-X^{(k)}$ part, which is not allowed in  $\pi_k(X^{(k)})$, but that the space is $k$-connected? (and because the space is CW by Whitehead up to homotopy it would have no cells in the range between $k$ and $1$, that's the crucial point there, right?

Comment: Being $k$-connected and $\pi_i(X)=0$ for $i=0,\dotsc,k$ are the same thing. The theorem in my answer applies perfectly well to the linked question as there we are attaching an $n$-cell to an $n$-dimensional CW-complex ($n=2$ in the example), so we only need the $k=n$ case here, in which $X^{(k)}=X$.

Comment: Also, let me add that they only needed that $\pi_2(S^1\times S^1)=0$. The torus is not $2$-connected, of course.